# Update nested Python list key using pop

Tags: python, json

I have a json file called pool.json which contains this:

```
{
  "pools": {
    "$poolId": {
      "nodes": {
        "$nodeId": {
          "bcm": {
            "address": {
              "ip": "10.10.10.10"
            },
            "password": "ADMIN",
            "username": "ADMIN"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my Python code:

```py
pool_id = ['123456']

json_pool = json.loads(read_json_file('pool.json'))

for i in pool_id:
    json_pool['pools'][i] = json_pool.pop(['pools']['$poolId'])
    print('json_pool: %s' % json_pool)
```

I'm trying to update `$poolId` with the value in `pool_id`(I know I've only got one pool_id. I just want to get this piece working before I do anything else). Ive been trying to do this with `pop` but am having no success when it's nested as in this case. I can get it working when I want to change a top level key. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does `123456` come from?

Comment: I just made that up. Later it'll be generated and read in from a different system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to execute `json_pool['pools'].pop('$poolId')` instead of `json_pool.pop(['pools']['$poolId'])`.